# Where isn't the transitive dependencies of my .Net Standard library copied into the executing assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.7.2

I have this dependency of projects:

`Client` [.NET 4.7.2] -> `Infrastructure` [.NET Standard 2.0] -> `ExternalLib` [dll]

When I try to call a method of `Infrastructure` that uses `ExternalLib` from the `Client` project, the compiler generates the following error:

> Error CS0012 The type `ClassX` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly `ExternalLib`

Is it possible to do it implicitly? I mean it shouldn't be needed to add this reference explicitly since it is already done in the `Infrastructure` project.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe when you initially said "recursive" you really meant "transitive" (as per your recent edit).

.NET, and .NET framework in particular doesn't really handle transitive references. It, as you have found, requires all dependencies to be explicitly referenced by the executing projects. An "implicit" reference isn't going to happen.

There seems to be better support for pulling in transitive dependencies in .NET Core, at least if the primary dependency is a Nuget package.

Comment: Considering IntelliSense and the type resolution during compilation seems to scan all references to know wich classes it has to autocomplete/wich ones are meant, such an automatic would propably backfire horribly and with a humongous time wasted. So there is even a really good reason not to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I just thought that there could be a way that MSBuild could check that the Infrastructure project has the reference to ExternalLib and add it to the Client project as well. It does not seem such a huge workload.

Comment: @Gofu It will do that... for a nuget package. For whatever reason the designers for .NET Framework (again, Core seems to handle this better) decided not to.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET even for .NET Core it would only work with nuget right?

Comment: @Gofu I can't say I've done enough multi-project Core projects to say for certain. I know the ProjectReference mechanic works a little different than Framework references do.

Comment: I will give it a try one of this days. Thanks for your help and for your time  @BradleyDotNET !

Comment: @Gofu, I checked it on a .NET Core repro project and indeed transitive references dont need to the added directly to uppermost project to be able to directly use one of its types.